# Android/Java: Layout automatic linebreak

Tags: java, android, layout

I have an activity in my android app that has to display a list of key-value pairs. Both, key and value, are string resources with non-uniform length.
The key shall be left aligned, and the value right aligned. If key and value fit into one line on the screen, they shall be displayed next to each other, while a linebreak shall separate key and value otherwise.

I created two layouts for the listitems, one with a linebreak and one without, depicted in the following screenshots:

[image: key-value pair one line]
[image: key value pair with linebreak]

How can I automatically display the correct listitem in the ListView of my activity?

Edit: upon request I also add my sourcecode (I do not think it is very helpful though, the differentiation between the two layout files has to be done in the section where I add the list layout fragments to my ListView. However, at this place I would have to solve many additional problems e.g. determining the length of a string resource, determining the space available for displaying the layout and also creating handlers that react to changes of the available space. Therefore I prefer the solution proposed by @bwt)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_key"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:text="Key"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:text="Value"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and with linebreak

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_6">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_key"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        tools:text="Key with a very long text constant"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listitem_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listitem_key"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        tools:text="Value with a very long text constant"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in the XML file give fix Layout_weight for both textview

Comment: @bugfreerammohan I do not want a fixed width textview. If one of the strings is short and the other is long, but both fit into the same line, they shall still be displayed in one line

Comment: add maxlines=1 in both textview

Comment: send your xml code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically wrapping views is a typical use case of Google's [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout). In your case it could be something like  :

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:alignContent="flex_start"
    app:flexWrap="wrap">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!-- right justified (using the remaining space) -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_flexGrow="1" />

</com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout>
```

More details in [Build flexible layouts with FlexboxLayout](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html)

Comment: Thank you, the FlexboxLayout solves my Problem. I had to add `implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'` to the `dependencies` section of my build.gradle file in order to use it though.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="10dp"
android:paddingTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/text1"/>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:id="@+id/notification_message"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/text1"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text1"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, if there is an option to create a single layout it would be even better. Unfortunately, this yields the following result. (I cannot attach images to comments, the key uses up several lines and the value is not starting in a separate line below)